# Exporting Functions from a Win32 Cross Built Static Library

Tags: c, static-libraries, static-linking, cross-build

I attempted to build a win32 static library using the `i686-w64-mingw32` cross-build toolchain.

I built the object files and the `mylib.lib` file via a Makefile:

```
$(program_RELEASE_NAME_WIN_STATIC): $(RELEASE_OBJS_WIN32_STATIC)
    i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar rcs $(BUILD_DIR_WIN32)/static/$@ $^

$(BUILD_DIR_WIN32)/static/%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(RELEASE_LINK_WIN32.c) $< -c -o $@
```

This gave me the static library `mylib.lib`. Inspecting this on the linux side with `nm` I can see all the constituent object files and the functions they contain

No when I inspect `mylib.lib` on a windows 10 VM, i.e.

```
DUMPBIN /EXPORTS mylib.lib
```

I get:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file mylib.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

           C .bss
           C .data
         6AC .drectve
        5EAC .rdata
         444 .rdata$zzz
       29900 .text
          38 .text.unlikely
```

None of the functions are being exported.

In the relevant header file I mark up the functions I want to export with `__declspec(dllexport)`

This worked fine when I was producing a .dll, i.e. the functions I marked for  export were the only ones that were visible in the .dll file

But for the static library equivalent nothing is being exported?

How are you meant to make functions visible in a win32 .lib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dumpbin /exports` lists the symbols exported by an executable or DLL. See [the DUMPBIN options documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972.aspx)

A static library isn't an executable or DLL. It's just a bag of object files
in Unix `ar` archive format (which is the same MS `LIB` format).

`dumpbin` analyses COFF binaries. When you run:

```
dumpbin /option... static.lib
```

it analyses each object file in `static.lib` according to `/option...`.
But:

```
dumpbin /exports file.obj
```

will never report any exports in the object file `file.obj` because an object
file isn't an executable or DLL either. It has no dynamic symbol stable.
Only an executable or DLL can expose symbols for dymamic linkage: it is supplied with
its dynamic symbol table when it is generated by the *linker*, which has no hand
in producing either an object file or static library.

If you now build an executable or DLL that links any function from your static library
that you have qualified with `__declspec(dllexport)` in the library's header file,
then the linker *will* add that function to the dynamic symbol table of the output
executable or DLL, and if you then `dumpbin /exports` on that executable or
DLL, you will see that the function is reported.

An object file may define global symbols. A global symbol (a.k.a public/external symbol) may or may not be
exported for dynamic linkage, depending on whether it is qualified `__declspec(dllexport)`
or not. A symbol must be global to be a DLL export.

If you run `dumpbin /symbols` on your static library, that will report all the
symbols in all the object files in the static library, and will classify them
as `External` or `Static`. The symbols that you have qualified as `__declspec(dllexport)`
will appear amoung the `External` symbols listed.

Comment: the functions always were visible weren't they? I just got hung up on not being able to see them using dumpbin /exports. The problems I attributed to this when I was trying to link I now think are just discrepancies between an out of date header file and whats in the .lib file. many thanks for removing the blinkers..